# How to show time in node.tpl.php that takes the configured timezone settings into account?

Tags: 7, theming, datetime

I have a custom content type and it has a date-time field. I have also a custom `node.tpl.php` to display this content type.

The timezone settings is done (at `admin/config/regional/settings`, Europe/Istanbul, +0300).

This is the code I print the date-time field.

```
<?php print format_date(strtotime($node->field_event_datetime[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']), $type = 'custom_event', $format = '', $timezone = 'Europe/Istanbul', $langcode = 'tr')?>
```

Although I set everything, it still shows the wrong time. For example it should be 10.00 but it shows 07.00. I also tried to set the timezone `NULL` but nothing changed.

**How to solve this problem?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a date from Date module using user timezone](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8657/how-to-print-a-date-from-date-module-using-user-timezone)

Comment: try `print render($content['field_event_datetime']);`